# Tkinter con clases

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como hago un menú como el blog de notas usando tkinter con clases?

Answer (score 1):

Hola aquí hay información acerca de tu pegunta espero que te funcione

https://docs.hektorprofe.net/python/interfaces-graficas-con-tkinter/editor-de-texto/

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Mi editor")

# Menú superior
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Nuevo")
filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir")
filemenu.add_command(label="Guardar")
filemenu.add_command(label="Guardar como")
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Salir", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=filemenu)

# Caja de texto central
texto = Text(root)
texto.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
texto.config(padx=6, pady=4, bd=0, font=("Consolas", 12))

# Menu y bucle de la aplicación
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

También he pensado, que de cara a abrir y guardar ficheros estaría bien mostrar un poco de información en la parte inferior. Podemos por ejemplo añadir una label abajo a la izquierda:

```
# Monitor inferior
mensaje = StringVar()
mensaje.set('Bienvenido a tu editor')
monitor = Label(root, textvar=mensaje, justify='right')
monitor.pack(side='left')
```